# escaping quotations in roxygen documentation in R

Tags: r, roxygen, roxygen2

I have an R function example in my documentation that needs to escape quotations:

```
#' @examples msearch("published_in:\"Journal of Ecology\"")
```

(Or at least I'm not clever enough to avoid escaping the quotation).  While this command works correctly in R, the roxygenize/document function converts this to double escapes

```
  msearch("published_in:\\"Journal of Ecology\\"")
```

in the .Rd file.  How do I get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've seen, the following line in an **roxygen documentation block**

```
#' @examples msearch("published_in:\"Journal of Ecology\"")
```

is converted to this in an ***.Rd file**

```
msearch("published_in:\\"Journal of Ecology\\"")
```

on its way to becoming the following, in the various **help file formats**

```
msearch("published_in:\"Journal of Ecology\"")
```

I'm guessing that is what you actually want in the final product. As it does in so many other ways, `roxygen` is simplifying the process of writing help files -- in this case by letting you type `\`s where you'd like them to actually appear. It does so by escaping the `\`s (as you'd otherwise have to do), which is what you saw when you peeked into the `*.Rd` file.

Comment: Ha, that's brilliant!  one more reason to roxygenize, I would have written the wrong thing in writing the .Rd file by hand.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask yourself whether that truly represents a problem. In R-help there is a frequent question raised about why this is TRUE:

```
nchar("\n") == 1
```

And further questions raised about how to remove an unwanted "\" .... which really isn't there.

If you want to use double quotes inside a string, then perhaps use single quotes to flank it? Or consider the tidy.source function: http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/formatR/html/tidy.source.html